# change theme function from a plugin, function_exists not working

Tags: php, wordpress, function

My theme has a function, the name is shz_get_images_property(), and it's checked by function_exists().

I want to change the function code.

Therefore, I created a plugin for this purpose. But when I activate the plugin I get a fatal error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare shz_get_images_property() (previously declared in ...../index.php on line 71

How to change the plugable theme function with plugin so that it does not fatal on plugin activation?

I don't want to change the name of the function, this function is used in many places in the theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your plugin you have to do the same as the theme does.

That is wrapping the function definition inside a conditional if-function_exists(*function-name*))-block.

```php
if (!function_exists('shz_get_images_property')) {
    function shz_get_images_property(/* take care to have the same as the original */) {
        /* ... your implementation ... */
    }
}
```

Otherwise you raise the incompatibility on whichever gets loaded first **during** plugin activation.

---

In general:

> The plugins are loaded right before theme [¹](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/26537/178)

Therefore, this should now have it your way ***after*** plugin activation.

Your plugin loads before the theme, the function will be defined in your plugin.

Then the theme loads, it sees the function is already defined, so the implementation from your plugin is in use.

---

¹ [*Between functions.php (theme), widgets, and plugins, which is loaded first?*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/26537/178)

For a detailed discussion of this standard PHP behaviour in context of WordPress, see the following two WordPress reports/tickets:

- [Cannot activate plugin which override function from pluggable.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/9915) (#9915; May 2009)
- [extract pluggable.php function logic into separate functions](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/8833) (#8833; Jan 2009)

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the reason. @hakre